# how to implement imagePicker in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview

i want to upload image in flutter webview 4.0.7,
but whenever i click on upload image, nothing happens on screen, but in (ios it works fine)

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _goBack(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: netState
            ? Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                child: WebViewWidget(
                    controller: _controller
                      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                      ..setNavigationDelegate(
                        NavigationDelegate(
                          onPageFinished: (String url) {
                            _controller.runJavaScript(
                                "document.getElementsByClassName('logo me-lg-4')[0].remove();" +
                                    "document.getElementsByClassName('cookies-card bg--default text-center cookies--dark radius--10px')[0].remove();");
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                      ..loadRequest(
                          Uri.parse('https://www.ilovepdf.com/unlock_pdf'))),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

Here is my code:

```
WebviewScaffold(
  url: 'example.com',
  withLocalStorage: true, //for upload files
);
```

Comment: i can't change the dependency. is there any alternative?